# call 2 different function.js file in wordpress, depending on page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to find how I can load 2 different function.js depending of the page.

when on "home", I want to load "function_2.js", and on the other pages of my website the original "function.js".

I need to change something in my function.php but I can't figure out what...

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[Check current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389669/check-current-url)

Get your current URL inside the handle_script() function and depending on the path, add function.js or function_2.js to the script variable.

Comment: thanks @Sefam, but I need to change this inside my function.php file.

Comment: I've modified my answer to answer the question more clearly. It's pretty much the same procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The way that code loads scripts is wrong. [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) is the proper hook for enqueuing scripts and styles on the front end, here is the general way how to set the conditions when loading scripts.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_frontend_scripts' );
function load_frontend_scripts() {      
    if ( is_home() ) {
        // load scripts and styles for home page
    } else {
        // load scripts and styles for pages other than home page
    }
    // load scripts and styles for all pages        
}
```

And [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) is the proper function to use for enqueuing stuff. Here is the general use of a function.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

In your case, for example, for `navigate.js` script replace:

- `'script-name'` with `'navigate'`
- `'/js/example.js'` with `'/_/js/navigate.js'`

, to get:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'navigate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/_/js/navigate.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

, and put that inside conditional block that meets the requirement.